# Get Stream IO React Native UnFollowing option not available

Tags: reactjs, react-native, feed, getstream-io

I am using Get Stream Io react native in my project https://github.com/GetStream/react-native-activity-feed

I see there is a functionality in the library of following a particular user, whereas the opposite is not available i.e. how to **unfollow** a user.

Please point me in the right direction on how to achieve this in react native

Answer (score 0):

Our library doesn't include the logic for following/unfollowing. It has a button that allows you to set it up yourself though. Which is the `FollowButton` you're talking about. You could do something like this:

```
<FollowButton
  followed={async () => {
    // check if you're following the user
    const following = await your_timeline_feed.following({filter: ['user:user_42'] })
    if (following) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }} // renders the button as "following"

  clicked={async () => {
    // your logic for following/unfollowing
    await your_timeline_feed.follow('user', 'user_42');
  }}
/>
```

Read more here:

- https://getstream.github.io/react-native-activity-feed/#!/FollowButton
- https://getstream.io/docs/following/?language=js

Comment: Thanks for your response, 
I am seeing a method `follow(
      targetFeedGroup: string,
      targetUserId: string | StreamUser<UserData>,
      options?: FollowRequestOptions,
    ): Promise<DurationResponse>; `
in class `StreamFeed` which can be taken from `StreamClient` using this method `feed<CustomActivityData>(
      feedGroup: string,
      userId?: string,
    ): StreamFeed<UserData, CustomActivityData>;` 

No unfollow method in StreamFeed class. Do I need to explicitly hit an endpoint to achieve this unfollowing a user activity? or I am missing something here

Comment: https://github.com/GetStream/react-native-activity-feed/blob/master/custom-definitions/getstream.js at line 216. Only follow method is available and no unfollow

Comment: Those are custom definitions. We also use these, there should be an unfollow method on the feed. https://github.com/GetStream/stream-js/blob/23b86825c0e16e47acd5ede7700f7e67544e7502/types/getstream/index.d.ts#L169